# Beginner's calculator, supporting M, D, A, S operations on two numbers

Tags: java, beginner, calculator

I'm new to programming and I sort of understand the concept of methods but, I am little overwhelmed by this program and want to shorten it using methods to make it easier to read and understand.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class NewCalculator { 
   public static void main(String[] args) { 
      String usrInput = "";
      String Num1Input = "";
      String Num2Input = "";
      int Num1Int = 0;
      int Num2Int = 0;
      int SumOfTwo = 0;
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner Num1 = new Scanner(System.in);
      Scanner Num2 = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Please Enter (M)ultiplication, (D)ivision, (A)ddition, or (S)ubtraction");
      usrInput = scnr.next();
      System.out.println(usrInput);
      if (usrInput.equals("M")|| usrInput.equals("m")||
          usrInput.equals("D")|| usrInput.equals("d")||
          usrInput.equals("A")|| usrInput.equals("a")||
          usrInput.equals("S")|| usrInput.equals("s")
      )
          { //If Bracket
           switch (usrInput) {//Switch Bracket
            case "M":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int * Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " * " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "m":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int * Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " * " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "D":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int / Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " / " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "d":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int / Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " / " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "A":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int + Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " + " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "a":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int + Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " + " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "S":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int - Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " - " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            case "s":
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 1");
            Num1Input = Num1.next();
            System.out.println("Please enter Number 2");
            Num2Input = Num2.next();
            Num1Int = Integer.parseInt(Num1Input);
            Num2Int = Integer.parseInt(Num2Input);
            SumOfTwo = Num1Int - Num2Int;
            System.out.println("The Answser to " + Num1Input + " - " + Num2Input + " Equals " + SumOfTwo);
            break;
            default: 
            System.out.println("We are in the case");
             break;
             }}else{
           System.out.println("You may only enter 'M', 'D', 'A', or 'S'");

          }

   }//Main Bracket
}//Class Bracket
```

Comment: Your title should give the purpose of the code and that should be explained in more detail in your description

Answer (score 1):

Actually breaking your code into methods is the least of your problems.

You can re-use the same `Scanner` for each input.

The `Scanner` class has a `nextInt()`.  Using this does away with the strings to store the input.

The `default:` case in the switch block handles any erroneous input, the conditional to check for that is superfluous.

Each `case:` block contains the same code.  You can ask for the numbers first then the operation.  This way you only write it once.

`case:` statements can be stacked to handle the same code for different `case:`'s.

Storing the numbers in an array allows you to pass them by reference to a method.

The `PrintStream` class(`System.out`) has a `Format` method which works well for concatenating the string output of different objects.

I've put all this together as well showed what can be done with a couple of methods:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer[] nums = {0,0,0};
    var in = new Scanner(System.in);
    getNums( in, System.out,nums);
    getResult(in, System.out, nums);
}
public static void getResult(Scanner in, PrintStream out,Integer[] nums){
    var goodInput = false;
    while (!goodInput) {
        goodInput = true;
        System.out.println("Please Enter (M)ultiplication, (D)ivision, (A)ddition, or (S)ubtraction");
        var usrInput = in.next();
        switch (usrInput) {
            case "M":
            case "m":
                nums[2] = nums[0] * nums[1];
                printResult(out, nums, '*');
                break;

            case "D":
            case "d":
                nums[2] = nums[0] / nums[1];
                printResult(out, nums, '/');
                break;

            case "A":
            case "a":
                nums[2] = nums[0] + nums[1];
                printResult(out, nums, '+');
                break;
            case "S":
            case "s":
                nums[2] = nums[0] - nums[1];
                printResult(out, nums, '-');
                break;
            default:
                out.println("You may only enter 'M', 'D', 'A', or 'S'");
                goodInput = false;
        }
    }        
}
public static void getNums(Scanner in, PrintStream out,Integer[] nums) {
    out.println("\nPlease enter the first number:");
    nums[0] = in.nextInt();
    out.println("\nPlease enter the second number:");
    nums[1] = in.nextInt();
}

public static void printResult(PrintStream out, Integer[] nums, char operand) {
    out.format("The Answser to %1$d %2$c %3$d = %4$d\n", nums[0], operand, nums[1], nums[2]);
}
```

This is just one of many ways this could be done.